# How do I Derive Bech32 Address from P2WPKH Output Script?

Tags: bech32-address, p2wpkh

I am building a small script to decode the raw coinbase transaction data into a human-readable viewer without external scripts to better my understanding around the subject.

I've noticed that there are many different types of output script types among transactions. (P2SH, P2PK (as seen in genesis block), P2PKH, etc)

One thing I have not been able to grasp is how to obtain the Base58 address in the new SegWit P2WPK and P2WSH types.

For example, [Block #542748](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000023805d7930291bb237472deb8ef27db6474afd472a0171) has this [coinbase transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/0b61523f9d48d74fc175518e1347e2b3c859d22505e3b5eba7b8fa40c86d0c8a) which my script determines to have a pay to witness public key (P2WPK) output with `97cfc76442fe717f2a3f0cc9c175f7561b661997` as the public key hash.

The full output script: `0[] PUSHDATA(20)[97cfc76442fe717f2a3f0cc9c175f7561b661997]`

Traditionally, in P2PK, P2PKH and P2SH I've used the image on [this thread](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49596/how-to-get-addresses-from-scriptpubkey-in-segwit-transactions) which works quite well.

When I apply the same method as the pubkeyhash (P2PKH) with the following operations I get a totally different address:

Append version byte:
`0097CFC76442FE717F2A3F0CC9C175F7561B661997`

SHA-256 Round 1:
`f756795a3b878d16bfa9e426a47d857830bb08a02e691f0487cbeac51b510f40`

SHA-256 Digest of Round 1: 
`ea7fe8c3b7680b79ff507c7d1b40bfc29ca8269bb1033cc84010506743cce404`

Append checksum 4 bytes: `0097CFC76442FE717F2A3F0CC9C175F7561B661997ea7fe8c3`

Base58 Encode: `1EqhwhM5t5NxedLoSuJ6BtBvUMLhanBLxa`

This is quite different than `bc1qjl8uwezzlech723lpnyuza0h2cdkvxvh54v3dn` which is listed on blockchain.info's website [here](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/0b61523f9d48d74fc175518e1347e2b3c859d22505e3b5eba7b8fa40c86d0c8a)

What's the best way to obtain the same address they have listed (starting with bc1)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Bech32 address from a public key?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70507/how-to-create-a-bech32-address-from-a-public-key)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay so I think I've figured it out for anyone else wondering what *exactly* you have to do to derive an address from this type.

In the case of the already mentioned transaction, ([coinbase of block 542748](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/0b61523f9d48d74fc175518e1347e2b3c859d22505e3b5eba7b8fa40c86d0c8a)) we first start by looking at the full decoded output script.

`0 PUSHDATA(20) 97cfc76442fe717f2a3f0cc9c175f7561b661997`

- The very first `OP_0` in the decoded script is the `witness version`
- We then take the data pushed (in our case `97cfc76442fe717f2a3f0cc9c175f7561b661997`) and convert it into binary
- Then we divide the binary into 5 bit sections. In our case: `10010 11111 00111 11100 01110 11001 00010 00010 11111 11001 11000 10111 11110 01010 10001 11111 00001 10011 00100 11100 00010 11101 01111 10111 01010 11000 01101 10110 01100 00110 01100 10111`
- Then we prefix the `witness version` in 5 bits `00000`
- Our binary then becomes `00000 10010 11111 00111 11100 01110 11001 00010 00010 11111 11001 11000 10111 11110 01010 10001 11111 00001 10011 00100 11100 00010 11101 01111 10111 01010 11000 01101 10110 01100 00110 01100 10111`
- The first part of the address is considered the `human readable` portion.
  This is always `bc` on the mainnet and `tb` on the testnet
- `1` is always the seperator between the `human readable` portion and the rest or `data`
- Now our address starts with `bc1` (mainnet is `bc` + seperator `1`)
- Now we map each 5 bits into the table [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki#bech32) - or [this alternative chart](https://pastebin.com/raw/7FHjDDXu) I've created
- `bc1` `qjl8uwezzlech723lpnyuza0h2cdkvxvh`
- The remaining 6 characters is a [checksum](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki#specification)
- Using the provided python code [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/sBQPZVCz) we can compute the checksum using the `bech32_create_checksum` function
- The first argument is the `human readable` portion as a STRING without the seperator (1)
- The second argument is an array of integers converted from our binary `data` portion

Our example:

```
bech32_create_checksum("bc", [0, 18, 31, 7, 28, 14, 25, 2, 2, 31, 25, 24, 23, 30, 10, 17, 31, 1, 19, 4, 28, 2, 29, 15, 23, 10, 24, 13, 22, 12, 6, 12, 23] )
```

This gives us:

```
[20, 21, 12, 17, 13, 19]
```

Which can be mapped with our table to `54v3dn`

Finally, we concatenate the `human readable`, `seperator`, `decoded data`, and the `checksum` for our final address: `bc1qjl8uwezzlech723lpnyuza0h2cdkvxvh54v3dn`

Comment: Good job answering your own question. You can cross reference with code for this available at https://github.com/sipa/bech32